# Solve S-expression with binary search tree

Tags: python, math, tree, binary

I have a string that gets parsed into a reader which puts it into an array as shown:

```
X = '(mul 5 (add 5 5))'
Y = parser(X)
y = ['mul', 5, ['add', 5, 5]]
```

I want to find the value of this expression `Y`. It has been suggested that I use a binary search tree and to traverse through the nodes. I just don't know how to do this. Note, I need this to work as a general routine, so that it will work for any string such as `'(mul (add 1 2) (log 8))`

Comment: I would not say binary search will help you. If your parser returns a tree which has 3 elements, so it is not a true binary tree. What you need is AST traversal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need, is recursion to step through the tree that's already given and aggregate the values from the tree leafs via the function at each node.

Here is a simplified example. A full example would need to handle many more functions, and also do error checking (domain, such as positiveness for `sqrt`, number of arguments, ...).

```py
import math

def get_value(expr):
    res = 0
    if type(expr) is list:
        if len(expr) > 0:  # check for empty list
            # recursively find the value of each argument
            arguments = [get_value(arg) for arg in expr[1:]]

            if expr[0] == 'mul':
                res = 1
                for arg in arguments:
                    res *= arg
            elif expr[0] == 'add':
                res = 0
                for arg in arguments:
                    res += arg
            elif expr[0] == 'log':
                if len(arguments) == 1:
                    res = math.log(arguments[0])
                elif len(arguments) == 2:
                    res = math.log(arguments[0], arguments[1])
    elif type(expr) is str:
        if expr == 'pi':
            res = math.pi
        elif expr == 'e':
            res = math.e
    elif type(expr) in [int, float]:
        res = expr
    return res


y = ['mul', 5, ['add', 5, 5]]
print(get_value(y)) # 50

print(get_value(['log', 10])) # 2.302585092994046
print(get_value(['log', 10, 10])) # 1.0
print(get_value(['mul', ['add', 1, 2], ['log', 8]])) # 6.238324625039507
```